# Facebook graph api call not working for web

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, httpclient

I have 2 calls to the graph api

- https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
- https://graph.facebook.com/me

the first one returns with success but the second one always returns an error (400 bad request).

Funny thing is that when i copy the created url in the browser it returns the data as expected, only if ran through the java code as an http client call it throws an error. The url is fine and the access_token is also correct have verified on facebook debug.

Can any one please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Here is the sample url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?access_token=sample_token&token_type=bearer&fields=id,name,email
```

Comment: the code to make the call      `javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
     response =
         client.target(graphApiUrl+"?"+paramStr)
             .queryParam("fields", "id,name,email").request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
             .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get();`

Comment: Look at the response _body_ that you get with the 400 status code; it is likely to contain more information about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that with v2.4 there is an additional field required called appsecret_proof. Supplying that with the sha256 of the client secret and the access token solved the problem. And that too only for a server call.. works just fine without it from a client call. Thats why the browser call was working fine but not the web server call.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the specify the `token_type` if you request Graph API objects. Try the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?access_token=sample_token&fields=id,name,email
```

Comment: Yeah but that's not the problem. The problem is that the URL created in the code does not work while I paste the same thing in browser works just fine